When using the JCheckBoxMenuItem, is there a way to disable the automatic check state toggle on click?
I have a JCheckBoxMenuItem of which I need to manually control the check state.  I don't see anything in the documentation to control that behavior.  I also tried creating my own custom subclass of JCheckBoxMenuItem and overriding processMouseEvent() with no change in behavior.
@Override
public void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e, MenuElement[] path, MenuSelectionManager manager)
{
    // Disable the default toggle behavior.
    if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED)  // checking for MOUSE_PRESSED or MOUSE_RELEASED does not work either
    {
        //setSelected(!isSelected());
        e.consume();
    }
    else
    {
        super.processMouseEvent(e, path, manager);
    }
}

Is it at all possible to do what I want?

@MarcePuente What I want is basically a regular menu item just with the ability to optionally show a check mark to the left.  One of the items will open a dialog box and the result of that dialog box will determine whether or not the menu item is checked.

Maybe JMenuItem kk = new JMenuItem(); JCheckBoxMenuItem it = new JCheckBoxMenuItem();
kk.addActionListener( (e) -> {
if( e.getSource().equals( kk )) {
it.setState( true );
}
});, change JMenuItem for your JComponent.

Are you asking for a kind of checkbox indicator which the end user cannot modify?

A JMenuItem is a subclass of AbstractButton and therefore, its behavior is controlled by its ButtonModel. You don’t have to implement a custom model in your case, as far as I understood, you want the appearance of a JCheckBoxMenuItem with a behavior of an ordinary JMenuItem, that is, an action will be triggered when the menu item is selected but without a(n automatic) change of the selected state. The action or some other part of the application may change the selected state independently. For this behavior, the DefaultButtonModel will do.
The following example program will toggle the JCheckBoxMenuItem on every second selection only:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
    JMenuItem menuItem = mb.add(new JMenu("Example"))
        .add(new JCheckBoxMenuItem("The Checkbox Item"));

    menuItem.setModel(new DefaultButtonModel()); // override behavior

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
    frame.setJMenuBar(mb);

    menuItem.addActionListener(ev -> customToggle(menuItem, frame));

    frame.setSize(300, 100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

static boolean notYet = true;

private static void customToggle(JMenuItem menuItem, JFrame frame) {
    if(notYet) {
        frame.setTitle("Select again to toggle");
        notYet = false;
    } else {
        frame.setTitle("Toggled");
        menuItem.setSelected(!menuItem.isSelected());
        notYet = true;
    }
}

